# PopUp StaysOpen when control goes

Tags: wpf, popup, lostfocus

In a Usercontrol Grid(Grid1) I have a textBox, two Buttons (Search and Save Buttons) and Two Popups(Popup1 and Popup2). Inside Popup2 there is a textBox and one button(Search). I wanted to hide the popups(both 1 and 2) when when the user click outside the Grid1. Rightnow I can hide the Popups but NOT able to click the button inside Popup2. As soon as I Click the SearchButton inside the Popup2 it hides Popups.

I have set the StaysOpen Property for both Popups to a bool prop like this: `StaysOpen="{Binding PopupStaysOpen}"`

Thanks.
-Menon

```
private void Grid1_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           (this.DataContext as ViewModel).PopupStaysOpen = false;               
        }
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you post your xaml code as well....